# Converting function from RxJS v5.x to v6

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular6

I've started with an Angular 5 template and converting it to Ang 6.
https://github.com/mmacneil/AngularASPNETCore2WebApiAuth

I'm aware RxJS has changed e.g. RxJS v5.x to v6.
So how to  I convert this code to v6 taken that the .map has been changed completely.

```
register(email: string, password: string, firstName: string, lastName: string,location: string, gender:string, birthDate:any): Observable<UserRegistration> {
let body = JSON.stringify({ email, password, firstName, lastName,location,gender,birthDate });
let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + "/accounts", body, options)
  .map(res => true)
  .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

UserRegistration

```
export interface UserRegistration {
email: string;  
password: string;
firstName: string;
lastName:  string;
location: string;
birthDate: any;
gender: string;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + "/accounts", body, options).pipe(
  map(res => true),
  catchError(this.handleError)
}
```

Worth knowing that if you don't want to convert all your RxJs code from 5 to 6 now you can install `rxjs-compat` which will support both versions (assuming you have 6 installed too)

When you upgrade ng5 to ng6 using `ng update` you will get `rxjs-compat` installed automatically. See https://blog.angular.io/version-6-of-angular-now-available-cc56b0efa7a4#7a6c for more info.

Comment: That worked on .map error  but unfortunately it didn't solve original problem I thought it might  which was not an error  in Ang v5. 

Error  Build:Type 'Observable<boolean>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<UserRegistration>'.

Answer (score 1):

use the pipe operator. replace the `catch` with `catchError`

```
return this.http.post(this.baseUrl + "/accounts", body, options)
  .pipe(
     map(res => true),
     catchError(this.handleError)
   )
}
```